# Unable to open video on Windows 7 using Opencv-Python when running program as an exe

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing a vision application using opencv-python. I am developing it on my personal Windows 10 computer but it needs to run on a Windows 7 device. I've run into an issue when trying to run the software on the windows 7 device, specifically, cv2 is unable to open the video file. I've boiled down the code for debugging purposes.

The code is:

```
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", required=False,
    help="path to the video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(args['video'])
(val, frame) = video_capture.read() 
print(val)

input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Using the command 'pyinstaller q1.py --onefile' I generate an executable for this program. When I run the executable using the command

```
q1 -v C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.avi
```

> True
>
> Press Enter to exit...

However, when I copy this executable onto my windows 7 device (via USB) and run the command

```
q1 -v C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.avi
```

I receive the error

> C:\Users\User\Desktop>q1 -v C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.avi
>   [ERROR:0] global
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (1 16)
>   cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
>
> OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cp
>   p:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number
>   (in the name of file): C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.avi in
>   function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
>
> False
>
> Press Enter to exit...

The file being passed is the same for both computers. While digging around in the opencv source code I found that cv:icvExtractPattern appears to be looking for some sort of standardized naming convention using numbers, and I can get rid of the error by including a number in the video file name (say "output1.avi"). This results in no error being raised, but the frame still not being read in. This also is not a problem on my windows 10 device.

Does anyone know what the issue may be here?

Additional information that may or may not be helpful:

- Python version 3.7.5 64-bit
- Pyinstaller version 3.6
- Cv2 version 4.2.0.34
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributed 14.25.28508 (x64) (Windows 10 machine)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributed (x64) - 14.0.23026 (Windows 7 machine)
- The windows 7 computer does not have Python installed

Comment: So you just copying exe file to win-7, and you are expecting it to work? without deployment? without the same environment in win-10?

Comment: I was under the impression that windows was forward/back compatible. Because I wasn't switching OS's I thought this wouldn't be an issue and that it was an opencv compatibility issue. I'll check into pyinstaller deployment. Thanks!

Comment: Update: The pyinstaller documentation pointed to the fact that windows 10 moved to the universal CRT and recommended installing the updated redistribution package to the windows 7 machine (2015-2019 (x64) - 14.26.28720). This did not solve my problem and I continue to receive the same error.